# On Got Focus vbNo to undo an option button works on click, but not arrow

Tags: ms-access

I have a Frame with Option buttons that are used to change the status of a time sheet. I want to have a message box confirmation pop up on the selection of one option and if the answer is no, then I want it to undo that selection. I added an event on Got Focus that works when you click on the button with the mouse. However, if you use keyboard arrows to go to the option button, the confirmation prompt shows, but even with a "No", the option button still changes. I imagine I can write my code better to fix this, though I see another workaround being disabling keyboard arrow using in the frame if that is possible. Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm a beginner VBAer. Below is the test coding I'm working on.

```
Sub Option25_GotFocus()
Dim TestNumber As Integer

TestNumber = Me!Frame20

If MsgBox("I certify that I have carefully reviewed this time sheet and that the hours reported on this time sheet, including all start and stop times, are accurate. Through acknowledgment, I am submitting and electronically signing my time sheet.", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then

Else

Me!Frame20.Value = TestNumber

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you use GotFocus instead of BeforeUpdate for validation?

Comment: I guess I could do that too, though how would I be able to track which option was selected prior to choosing the option that makes the message box show? I am not attached to any solution, just want to be able to have the option return to what it was previously if the message box is "no".

Comment: Why would you need to? Have you researched the event? If user cancels edit then control will revert to old value.

Comment: Ah, it appears using BeforeUpdate works! Thank you!